# How do I get the last modified date of a file in multiple directories?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to to make a simple batch script that compares 4 files in 4 different directories and gets the "Last Modified" file into a variable. The closest I came was sorting using 'dir' and sorting it by modified date using:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir *.txt /b /s /a-d /od C:\testing ') do SET newest1=%%G
```

However, this will only work on one directory. So my question is, how do I determine what the last modified file is from more than one directory (actually need it for four different folders).

I've tried:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /b /s /O:D /T:W C:\testing\test1\test.txt C:\testing\test2\test2.txt') DO SET NEWEST=%%i
```

But that doesn't work with multiple directories. I'm guessing since I'm dealing with more than one directory that sorting won't work, so what else can I use?

Some notes:

- Need to compare files down to the seconds
- Some files can get rather large, so copying them all into another folder then comparing them would take too long and it wouldn't be very efficient

Comment: Do the files have a common filespec? Details about the files can help get you the simplest solution. if the files are on the same drive then moving is a very swift operation, and they can be moved back - but we know little about the files.  Robocopy can be used to get the latest file too - depending on where the files are.

Comment: You say "4 files" - so do you know the filenames - or are the filenames variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your system is Windows Vista or later (or if you are allowed to download the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools), you can use `robocopy` to copy the 4 files into a folder. Yes, i have readed the notes. The trick is that the `/create` switch in robocopy generate a 0 bytes instance of the file in the target folder but maintains the timestamp of the files. Then you can use your first code to solve the problem

If you can not use robocopy, but administrador rights are not a problem

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%f in (
        "c:\\somewhere\\file1.txt"
        "c:\\other\\place\\file2.txt"
        "c:\\somewhere\\file2.txt"
    ) do for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%a in ('
        wmic datafile where name^="%%~f" get lastModified /value
    ') do set "_t[%%a]=%%~f"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set _t[') do set "lastFile=%%a"
    set "lastFile=%lastFile:\\=\%"

    echo %lastFile%
```

This code uses `wmic` to retrieve the timestamp of the files, store in an array in environment using the timestamp as index. Then retrieve the list, that will be in ascending order. The last element in the array is the newer file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However, the code you provided does not work for me (testing it on Windows 7 machine with admin rights). I simply replaced the file names with actual files and tried running it. It gives the following error three times: "No Instance(s) Available."   It seems to fail when it get's to the for statement. I have verified that the path names are correct and that there are no spaces/special characters.

Comment: @steven, my fault, i didn't remove all the test code and the loop was iterating over a non existing file (the reason for the `wmic` answer "No Instance(s) Available"). Code updated. Anyway, for windows 7, the 4 `robocopy` operations can be faster than 4 queries to wmi.